# Compare object field in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

Where `type` refers to another table:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    """ Model for Applicant Type

    Attributes:
        type: string
    """

    type = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Override for __str__ method
        """
        return self.type

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobs_type'
```

I can access an object's type in the template by simply writing the following:

```
<h3>{{applicant.type}}</h3>
```

Where `applicant` is the Applicant object. However, when I try and compare the type to a String, the comparison fails:

```
{% if applicant.type == "Driver" %}
    <h3>{{applicant.type}}</h3>
{% else %}
    <h3>{{applicant.type}} does not equal "Driver"</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Printing:

```
Driver does not equal "Driver"
```

Is there a better way to compare object fields in a Django template?

The "Type" field in the jobs_type table of the database is a varChar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably "Driver" is in the `type` field of the Type model instance. So you can compare against that field.

```
{% if applicant.type.type == "Driver" %}
```

Comment: That makes more sense! Thanks, I knew it was something silly that I was missing.